How to make "pod install" command use Ruby 3.3.5?
On my MacOS Sonoma 14.6.1 I had system Ruby 2.6.10 and installed the latest Ruby version 3.3.5.
Then I tried to build a project with CocoaPods and some errors have occurred during the build. When I tried to do
pod install --repo-update

among other error information I got the following:
  CocoaPods : 1.15.2
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin23]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
        Host : macOS 14.6.1 (23G93)
      Xcode : 15.4 (15F31d)
        Git : git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-146)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : cocoapods - git - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ cc39f51f6e227c53fb7293500d65c918e8f0a635

which means that CocoaPods uses my system Ruby 2.6.10 while the command
gem env

shows Ruby version 3.5.19:
  ProductName:            macOS
  ProductVersion:         14.6.1
  BuildVersion:           23G93
  admin@son YandexMobileAdsExample % ruby -v
  ruby 3.3.5 (2024-09-03 revision ef084cc8f4) [x86_64-darwin23]
  admin@son YandexMobileAdsExample % gem env
  RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.5.19
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.3.5 (2024-09-03 patchlevel 100) [x86_64-darwin23]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/admin/.gem/ruby/3.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/admin/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-darwin-23
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
     - /Users/admin/.gem/ruby/3.3.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /opt/local/bin
     - /opt/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
     - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
     - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin

and
% ruby -v

shows the right version:
ruby 3.3.5 (2024-09-03 revision ef084cc8f4) [x86_64-darwin23]

How to make "pod install" command use Ruby 3.3.5?

You should uninstall your brew version of Ruby, then use a Ruby version manager like rbenv to install Ruby, and then install cocoapods without sudo. This will give you the best environment and will not interfere with the system Ruby.

@Casper I was able to build it with Ruby 3.3.5, thanks!
